# Loading External Application Configuration In Spring Web Application

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, jaxb

In my multi-module spring MVC web application, I have added a module which is a kind of API(Which was not Spring managed). The API has a configuration file i.e. config.xml(resides in /main/java/resource). I injected API as an dependency to a spring managed module.

```
<bean id="conf" class="a.b.c.ConfLoader" factory-method="load">
    <constructor-arg  type="java.lang.String" value="config.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="builder" class="a.b.c.Builder">
    <constructor-arg ref="conf" />
</bean>
```

Using JAXB Unmarshalling, converting XML to Object

```
public static Configuration load(String configXML) {
    JAXBElement<Configuration> unmarshalledObject = null;
    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext
                .newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshalledObject = (JAXBElement<Configuration>) unmarshaller
                .unmarshal(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(configXML));

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    }
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    if (unmarshalledObject != null) {
        config = unmarshalledObject.getValue();
    }
    return config;
}
```

This works fine as long as config.xml resides under application's(API) resource folder(/main/java/resource).

I have a requirement to keep config.xml to out side the application as it has environment specific configuration.

I tried to keep the config.xml into tomcat's conf directory but it does not get loaded. I need to load it from some other location other than application.

Any direction and help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: Can you add it to classpath via command line at startup? (I think this would go in setenv.bat / .sh)

Answer (score 0):

Method `unmarchal` takes File as a parameter, so you could do:

```
 unmarshalledObject = (JAXBElement<Configuration>) unmarshaller
                .unmarshal(new File(pathtofile));
```